# Groovy CodeVisitorSupport Call Method

Tags: java, methods, groovy, closures, abstract-syntax-tree

In the following gist I am walking through a closure and transforming its contents into a SQL WHERE statement based on comparison operators. It is based on Groovy's DataSet.

https://gist.github.com/mnbbrown/6190466

I'm stuck with how to go about calling a groovy MethodCallExpression that is part of the closure. I need to get the method return value and append it to the where string buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The AST transform wouldn't typically generate a where-clause directly. Instead, it would generate program code that when executed generates a where-clause. This would also mean that the `MethodCallExpression` can stay as-is.